# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE does not clear memory afterwards

Tags: mysql, laravel, memory-management, mariadb, load-data-infile

I am creating a CSV-importer that loads the CSV-file in a MariaDB 10.3.23 database. For this I am using the following code inside a Laravel 7 with PHP 7.4 environment:

```
$query = <<<eof
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$this->filePath'
        INTO TABLE `$tableName`
        $characterSet
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$this->delimiter'
        ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
eof;

DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
```

I am using ploi.io to deploy and monitor my website, which shows the following screen on the monitoring-page:

[image]

The RAM-display-line is at 15% when I have restarted the MariaDB service, but whenever I start a new import (and thus a new LOAD DATA INFILE), the amount of used RAM jumps up (which isn't weird), and stays up. The difference in height of RAM-line is due to a difference in CSV-filesize. It looks like it does the data-load, and doesn't empty the memory that was being used for it afterwards.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

ps. I am not great at infra/devops, so if you guys need more information let me know.

Comment: Is this causing an issue, like when you want to import the next file, mysql runs out of memory? Because if this is not an issue, then I would not spend much time resolving it.

Comment: It's possible that the operation is cached. The memory will probably be cleared when it's needed for other things. Garbage collection is a very expensive process, it's typical for software to hold off on doing it unless really necessary.

Comment: Jep, eventually it will cause a memory limit exceeded error and will crash mysql. With every new import i do (could be more than 100), the RAM just heaps up and will not be cleared until the crash of a manual mysql restart.

Comment: Is there a way for LOAD DATA INFILE to not be cached? It seems to me that it is a one-time thing action per file ("put all the records in the database").

Answer (score 0):

Do `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'the_file_name';`

Then add Data_length + Index_length.  Is that about the amount of space consumed, but not released?

What is the value of `innodb_file_per_table`?

Comment: For some reason it's not finding the file name, when I look for the file named "productfeed.csv" and use `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'productfeed';`.

Also, the value for `innodb_file_per_table` is 1. 

Does this help? :D